# Getting the number of a chapter-numbered theorem but without the chapter number

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems

Suppose in Chapter **3** I have Theorem **3**.17. I need to get the "17",  NOT the "3.17" which would readily be obtained using `\label` then `\ref`. How do i do that?

**Edit:**
(Probably a more relaxing condition): I need that number "17" mostly inside or near (just below) the current theorem environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. If I remember correctly, you can find this feature in [`varioref` package](http://http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref). I can't provide you more details since I don't really know that package.

Comment: I believe this has already asked before. Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/cross-referencing-in-multiple-chapters help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to make a reference to a theorem, but just the number of the upcoming theorem, say

```
\number\value{theorem}
```

at the position you want to have it. (This solution assumes that `theorem` is the counter responsible for the theorem environment.)

Changing the output of `\ref` can be done with `varioref` package, as stated by user tohecz before.

If you want to advance the counter by one, there are three possibilties, which should not be applied simultaneously:

```
\stepcounter{theorem}
```

or

```
\refstepcounter{theorem}
```

or

```
\addtocounter{theorem}{1}
```

The last method can be applied if you want to add (or even subtract) another value -- just exchange the number '1' by a positive or negative integer.

Comment: This works! I never knew this. Now, how do I add a number to the produced number? Something like `\number\value{theorem}\plusone`

Comment: @fajar: I have added some text and pieces of code in my solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to know the current value of the `theorem` counter you can also use

```
\the\value{theorem}
```

If you want to add a number to this value, you can use the construct

```
\the\numexpr<calculation>\relax
```

For example, to add 1 to that value

```
\the\numexpr\the\value{theorem}+1\relax
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}  % only for the example

\chapter{Test}

\setcounter{theorem}{16} % only for the example

\begin{theorem}
  This is my theorem
\end{theorem}

\noindent Here I want to know which is the number of the current theorem:
\the\value{theorem}

\noindent Here I want to know which is the number of the next theorem: 
\the\numexpr\the\value{theorem}+1\relax

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]