# How to reference sections in other parts mentioning the part?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, parts

I have an article class document with a structure like this.

- Part A

  - Section 1
  - Section 2
- Part B

  - Section 1
  - Section 2

I want to reference Section 1 in part A from Section 2 in part B.
When I reference a section in another part using `\ref`, `\vref` or `\cref` I get

> As seen in Section 1.

Since that appears in Part B, the reader would assume I'm talking about section 1 in part B, but I mean section 1 in part A.

Desired output:

> As seen in Section 1 in Part A.

Now comes the tricky part.
Most of my references are for within the same section. If I'm in Part B and I'm referencing something in Part B, I just want to say

> As seen in Section 1

Not

> As seen in Section 1 in Part B

Is there some combination of `varioref`,`hyperref`, `cleveref` and whatever else which can do that with a single command? (Bonus points if it is hyperlinked and can include smart page numbers like `\vref`)

I suppose redefining section numbers to be of the form `A.1` would work. Is there a way of doing it without that?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel} %do I need this? Gummi throws an error if I leave it out. I dunno.
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\part{First Part}\label{sec:first part}

\section{section in first part}\label{sec:in first part}

\part{Second Part}\label{sec:second part}

\section{section in second part}\label{sec:in second part}

\Cref{sec:in first part} is cool
%desired output: Section 1 in Part A is cool.


\Cref{sec:in second part} is also cool.
%desired output: Section 1 is also cool.

\end{document}
```

Edit: The penultimate line is supposed to say 'this part' not 'another part'. Disambiguated the reference sentences.

Comment: I don't recommend spaces in the label name

Comment: Why? I've never had any troubles using spaces in labels.

Comment: There might be cases when the label name has to be processed further, the spaces make this is a little bit trickier.

Comment: \label {section} then \autoref{section} works too

Answer (score 6):

Since there is no direct information about section of which part in the standard `\LaTeX` reference system the solution of such a 'context' aware referencing is involved with a lot of ugly hacks...

... if one uses the standard reference system ;-)

However, with Heiko Oberdiek's `zref` package and the help of `cleveref` this job can be done with less hacking.

The key is to write additional data as label - meta information such as counter name, part value, section value (called properties) etc with a `\zref@labelbyprops`  to the `.aux` file and retrieving the relevant information with `\zref@extract` (which is expandable, fortunately!)

The `cleveref` package is not really needed here, but it's nice to exploit its `\crefname` features by using the macros `\cref@<type>@name` etc. macros once the counter type is known.

Please note that the new macro `\zclabel` is needed, instead of the traditional `\label` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[counter,user,hyperref]{zref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
}{
  \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
  \providecommand{\hyperlink}[2]{#2}
}

\zref@newlist{sectionprop}
\zref@newprop{partinfo}[-1]{\thepart}
\zref@newprop{sectioninfo}[-1]{\number\value{section}}

\newcommand{\zclabel}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{partinfo,sectioninfo,anchor,counter}%
}

% Wrapper macros that extract the reference counter type and the reference value -- this way, no additional \label is necessary

\newcommand{\countercref}[1]{%
  \expandafter\csname cref@\zref@extract{#1}{counter}@name\endcsname\ \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{sectioninfo}}%
}

\newcommand{\Countercref}[1]{%
  \expandafter\csname Cref@\zref@extract{#1}{counter}@name\endcsname\ \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{sectioninfo}}%
}


\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  % Check first whether the label is defined at all, otherwise \Countercref etc. would fail!
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{}{% 
    % Preexpand some information
    \edef\@tmp@a{\zref@extract{#1}{partinfo}}%
    \edef\@tmp@b{\thepart}%
    \ifx\@tmp@b\@tmp@a\relax% Compare \thepart with the result of the zref - label - value for par
    \Countercref{#1} in this \partname%
    \else
    \Countercref{#1} in \partname\ \zref@extract{#1}{partinfo}%
    \fi
  }%
}

}
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}

\begin{document}
\part{First Part}
\section{section in first part}\zclabel{sec:infirstpart}
\part{Second Part}
\section{section in second part}\zclabel{sec:insecondpart}
\secref{sec:infirstpart} is cool and \secref{sec:insecondpart} is cool too, but \secref{sec:inthirdpart} is even better!
\part{Third Part}
\section{section in third part}\zclabel{sec:inthirdpart}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Overleaf` (maybe it works in other environment too) you can address to the official ["Cross referencing sections, equations and floats > Referencing sections and chapters"](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Cross_referencing_sections%2C_equations_and_floats#Referencing_sections_and_chapters)

And use the following construction:

```
\section{section in first part}\label{sec:in_first_part}

Section \ref{sec:in_first_part} is cool
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show an screenshot, is the part no. also showed?

Comment: @Mensch Hello! Thanks, the image is added!