# How to find out what type of section a given \ref refers to

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering

I am writing a document using KOMAscript's `scrreprt` class, and I am writing a custom macro (`\xref`) to format text used for cross-references.

This macro takes the label name as an argument: `\xref{mylabel}`

I want to generate a different text depending on whether the label refers to a chapter/section/subsection (numbered by default) or to a subsubsection/paragraph (unnumbered by default).

How can I check this? Any of the following two would do:

1. Check if the label refers to a chapter/section/subsection (or the opposite: Check if the label refers to a subsubsection/paragraph)
2. Check if the label refers to a numbered item

Comment: Package `zref` is a good friend, see for example my answer to this question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312060/how-to-reference-sections-in-other-parts-mentioning-the-part

Comment: You can use `cleveref` as well

Comment: Well, what do you think `scrreport` makes use of in the final end? ;-) Using no extra packages, this you have to do redefinitions in the `\label` - `\ref` system. This requires some `LaTeX` skills. I don't see the point to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Even `hyperref`'s `\autoref` can be used for this.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions of alternative packages. What I am looking for is a way to test the type of element a label refers to.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: But that's not expandable (as far as I can remember), which is necessary, to make it working in checks... and it is in an extra package ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Depends on what is wanted. Maybe the output of `\autoref` is just the wanted result. Maybe redefining the names may be enough. Maybe not.

Comment: @Grodiguez: LaTeX itself does not provide a type of element for labels. So you either need to use an additional package or you have to extend the label mechanism of LaTeX similar to such existing packages. I would recommend to use an existing package.

Comment: Your second test idea -- "Check if the label refers to a numbered item" -- has no chance of working, unless you somehow massively rewrite the code that underlies the `\label` macro (and likely break all kinds of stuff in the  process...). By default, the `\label` instruction looks for the counter variable that was most recently incremented via a `\refstepcounter` instruction. However, if some item is not numbered to begin with, there is simply no such association to latch on to. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued from preceding comment)  You should probably look into the far more general (but also more elaborate) `\hyperlink`-`\hypertarget` machinery of the `hyperref` package. But then, you seem to be averse to loading any external packages...

Comment: @Mico I am not averse to loading external packages if they help me to do what I want to do.

Comment: @Mico: In fact, it is possible (with some assumptions) to check whether the label refers to a numbered identity: `hyperref` uses a `*` in the anchor name. As long as nobody screws up the `\theH....` output `zref` can be used to exploit the anchor name and check, whether there is a `*` inside (and of course nobody should define a counter name with `*` inside)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Thanks for pointing this out. When I wrote the earlier comment, I was thinking mostly about the "basic"-LaTeX `\label` instruction. Good to know that `hyperref` modifies the `\label` macro in interesting ways.

Comment: @Mico: Actually, I had to think about it for some days until I had the idea with the anchor check. As said above ... it is not failsafe, of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the update for referring to `unnumbered/numbered` structure unit and checking at the end.

Without using any extra packages, only `\renewcommand, \let, \pdfstrcmp` etc. are used and writing a `\@namedef` to the `.aux` file.

It requires two runs (which are needed anyway, since we're dealing with labels!)

Use `\extractlabeltype{labelname}` and `\checklabeltype` with true/false branch.

It assumes that no other package is involving with `\label` and `\ref`, i.e. no `hyperref` or `cleveref` is supported.

```
\documentclass{book}


\makeatletter
\let\latex@@refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\let\latex@@label\label%


\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{%
  \gdef\lastrefsteppedcounter{#1}%
  \latex@@refstepcounter{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\global\string\@namedef{label#1}{\lastrefsteppedcounter}}
   \latex@@label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\extractlabeltype}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{label#1}%
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\checklabeltype}[4]{%
\ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{\extractlabeltype{#1}}{#2}
#3%
\else
#4%
\fi
}


\begin{document}



\chapter{Foo} \label{foo}


\section{Foosection}\label{foosection}

\checklabeltype{foosection}{section}{Yes, it is section}{No, it is something different}

\checklabeltype{foo}{section}{Yes, it is section}{No, it is something different}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** with checking for unnumbered/numbered issues.

Please not that this deliberately depends on the assumption that the anchor name of a unnumbered structure unit has a `*` in it, so playing around with `\theH...` macros is no good idea ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[hyperref,counter]{zref}% Using the counter mechanism behind `nameref`
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\latex@@label\label%

  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
    \zref@label{#1}%
    \latex@@label{#1}%
  }
  % Get the underlying counter type
  \newcommand{\extractlabelcounter}[1]{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
      ???????}{%
      \zref@extract{#1}{counter}%
    }%
  }
  % Get the anchor name for hyperref or nameref -> has a `*` inside if it is unnumbered
  \newcommand{\extractlabelanchor}[1]{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
      ???????}{%
      \zref@extract{#1}{anchor}%
    }%
  }
}

% Check if there's a `*` inside of the anchor name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \checkifnumbered#1#2#3{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\extractlabelanchor{#1}}
  \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_tl {*} {#2} {#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother


\newcommand{\checklabeltype}[4]{%
  \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{\extractlabelcounter{#1}}{#2}
  #3%
  \else
  #4%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo} \label{foo}

\section*{An unnumbered section} \label{unnumbered}

\section{Foosection}\label{foosection}

\checklabeltype{foosection}{section}{Yes, it is section}{No, it is something different}

\checklabeltype{foo}{section}{Yes, it is section}{No, it is something different}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First \label{enumfirst}
\item Second \label{enumsecond}
\end{enumerate}

\checklabeltype{enumsecond}{enumi}{It is a numbered item and has the value \ref{enumsecond}}{}

In \nameref{unnumbered} we have an \checkifnumbered{unnumbered}{unnumbered}{numbered} \extractlabelcounter{unnumbered}


In \nameref{foo} we have an \checkifnumbered{foo}{unnumbered}{numbered} \extractlabelcounter{foo} whereas
 \nameref{foosection} is a \checkifnumbered{foosection}{unnumbered}{numbered} \extractlabelcounter{foosection}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a solution that's compatible with the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Is it? I did not check. I doubt that `cleveref`'s `\label[...]{...}` will like this ;-).

Comment: @Grodriguez: It's a little bit more complicate with `zref` but more flexible, currently I am not sure that `cleveref` is the right package for your needs

Comment: @ChristianHupfer On testing this a bit more I noticed that it does not work as required. If you define a label for a subsubsection (which is unnumbered in the `book` class), `extractlabeltype` thinks it is a "subsection"....

Comment: @Grodriguez: Yes, but in this case labelling a unnumbered subsubsection does not make any sense, does it? ;-) Using my solution or not, it will still use the label of the preceding `subsection`, that's how LaTeX is defined.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, that was exactly the point of my original question. I want to check the label type so that I can use \nameref for subsubsections and paragraphs, but \ref for chapters, sections and subsections. And I want to do this in an automated way (not manually)

Comment: @Grodriguez: An unnumbered section level does **not** use `\refstepcounter`, so you won't have a working label (it will use the label value of the last `\refstepcounter` before (which is the case I've described in my last comment) and that label is wrong then. It won't work with `hyperref`, `zref`, `cleveref` etc. That's why I wrote it requires some insight into the label/ref mechanism and LaTeX skills...

Comment: `\label` to unnumbered structure level fails. Period!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, `\label` doesn't fail. I can `\nameref` to an unnumbered section just fine. It is `\ref` with an unnumbered section that will fail. That is why I am looking for a way to tell if a label refers to an unnumbered section or to a numbered one, so that I know whether I need to use `\nameref` or `\ref`.

Comment: @Grodiguez: That's just because hyperref changes refstepcounter. \nameref is not expandable, by the way

Comment: @Grodriguez: Alright, but nearly impossible without using other packages

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your updated solution works like a charm. This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Grodriguez: Well, that's nice. Happy TeXing!