How can I reference a footnote with its chapter using cleveref?
I want to include the chapter number in references to footnotes in the form "footnote 1.1". To do this, I use \labelformat. However, this also affects the behavior of \footref when I want copy a former footnotemark from the same chapter -- in that case, I do not want to include the chapter number.
Minimum failing example:
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% ensure footnote references include chapter number
\labelformat{footnote}{\thechapter.#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

This is a test.\footnote{\label{footnote}This is a footnote.}

This uses the same footnote\footref{footnote}. % expected: ¹ actual: ¹·¹

\chapter{Chapter Two}

Here is a fully qualified link to the former footnote: \cref{footnote}. % correct: footnote 1.1

\end{document}

How can I define different reference formats for \footref (or any other command that achieves the same) and \cref?

I experienced with \creflabelformat but was unable to include the correct chapter number there.

I also tried temporarily resetting the label format but this surprisingly had no effect on the wrapped \footref:
\NewDocumentCommand{\localfootref}{m}{%
  \labelformat{footnote}{#1}%
  \footref{#1}%
  \labelformat{footnote}{\thechapter.#1}%
}




changing the label format will change it for everything. if you always use \cref for references to other chapters, just redefine the cleveref format for footnote references so it incorporates the chapter.

There are a limitted number of things saved by \label: \@currentlabel, \@currentlabelname, \@currentHref and \thepage.  To save anything else, one can use what amousts to two labels.  For example, the \subref(foo) (subcapton package) is equivalent to \ref{sub@foo}

@cfr Could you elaborate? If I use \crefformat{footnote}{\thechapter.#1}, the chapter will always refer to the current chapter, not that of the footnote.

@JohnKormylo To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Regular references are able to use the chapter number, so why should this not work just for crefs?

the simplest may be to use something like varioref together with cleveref and then set things up so you don't get the prefix in the same chapter. but I would probably use \cref consistently in that case and drop \footref. (or may it an alias for \cref.) you can strip the prefix from the reference - cleveref provides a macro specifically for this purpose.

If you look at the aux file, you iwll find
\newlabel{footnote}{{1.1}{1}{}{Hfootnote.1}{}}
where 1.1 is \@currentlabel, 1 is the page number, \@currentlabelname is empty and  Hfootnote.1 is \@currentHref.  You will also find
\newlabel{footnote@cref}{{[footnote][1][1]1.1}{[1][1][]1}{}{}{}}
where [footnote][1][1]1.1 is \@currentlabel, etc.  So cref has lots of room to add additional information, but you have to know how it is used.
But if all you want is to add information, you don't need cref at all.  In this case, I used the fact thet \nameref wasn't being used.  The tricky bit was doing it as one hyperlink instead of two.
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterlabel}[1]% #1 = unmodified label name
{\bgroup
  \edef\@currentlabelname{\thechapter}%
  \label{#1}%
\egroup}

\newcommand{\chapterref}[1]{\hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{Doc Start}}%
  {\nameref*{#1}.\ref*{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

This is a test.\footnote{\chapterlabel{footnote}This is a footnote.}

This uses the same footnote\footref{footnote}. % expected: ¹ actual: ¹·¹

\chapter{Chapter Two}

Here is a fully qualified link to the former footnote: \chapterref{footnote}. % correct: footnote 1.1

\end{document}


Thank you. I hoped it would have been easier because I use cleveref consistently for all kinds of references in my thesis, but I added the missing label text footnote  in front of your \chapterlabel definition and redefined \cref to conditionally dispatch via https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351559/221054 to it.
